# Disable Submit Actions and Inputs for adaptive cards in BotFramework-Webchat

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards, web-chat

I am trying to find a way to disable the Action.Submit action type and all inputs of adaptive cards that are not the most recent message in the conversation. I found this option of using the `attachmentMiddleware` of the BotFramework-Webchat used in React.

```js
const attachmentMiddleware = () => next => ({ activity, attachment, ...others }) => {
      if (attachment.contentType === "application/vnd.microsoft.card.custom") {
        attachment.contentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive"
      }
      const { activities } = store.getState()
      const messageActivities = activities.filter(
        activity =>
          activity.type === "message" &&
          typeof activity.suggestedActions === "undefined" // to filter out suggested actions
      )
      const recentBotMessage = messageActivities.pop() === activity
      const AdaptiveCardContent = Components.AdaptiveCardContent
      switch (attachment.contentType) {
        case "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive":
          return (
            <AdaptiveCardContent
              actionPerformedClassName="card__action--performed"
              content={
                attachment.content
              }
              disabled={!recentBotMessage}
            />
          )
        default:
          return next({ activity, attachment, ...others })
      }
    }
```

This solution sets the disabled property in the AdaptiveCardContent Component for not recent messages by the bot and works really well except for Action.OpenUrl actions on containers.
Any Action.OpenUrl will have no functionality, but will look like it is still an enabled button. Example Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of a chat, displaying the above mentioned behavior.]

As seen in the screenshot, the "primary" actions at the bottom of type Action.Submit are disabled correctly. Now the Action.ToggleVisibility ("Toggle", which changes the visibility of an text) and the Action.OpenUrl ("Open in new tab") are not disabled. The Action.ToggleVisibility ("Toggle") works as it did before, which is our intended behavior and fine. But the Action.OpenUrl which looks like it is still clickable, is in fact not.

I think it is because of the following line #107 and #108 in [`botframework-webchat\src\adaptiveCards\Attachment\AdaptiveCardRenderer.tsx`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/main/packages/bundle/src/adaptiveCards/Attachment/AdaptiveCardRenderer.tsx#L107):

```js
// Only listen to event if it is not disabled and have "tapAction" prop.
  const handleClickAndKeyPressForTapAction = !disabled && tapAction ? handleClickAndKeyPress : undefined;
```

But I do not understand why the Action.ToggleVisibility actions work just fine and the Action.OpenUrl actions, which html elements are not disabled and have no `aria-disabled="true"` properties, have no handling for clicking them.

I tried a completely different way of achieving this behavior by modifying the card, that is given to the `AdaptiveCardContent`, but this way leads to not wanted effects like loosing the inputted values of users after disabling the inputs, since it seems the `usePersistValuesModEffect` is overwritten or something, or like some unwanted effects from re-rendering the changed adaptive card.

Does anybody know if this is a bug or intended behavior of the disabled property and if so if there is a good working solution to disable inputs and only Action.Submit actions of adaptive cards?

**EDIT:**

This is the `attachment.content` value, meaning the adaptive card that is given to the `<AdaptiveCardContent>` component:

```
{
    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
    "content": {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.3",
        "speak": "",
        "body": [
            {
                "type": "Container",
                "id": "content",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "weight": "bolder",
                        "text": "A title",
                        "wrap": true
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Container",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                "id": "descriptionPreview",
                                "text": "Some Content",
                                "wrap": true
                            }
                        ],
                        "spacing": "medium",
                        "separator": true
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Container",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "Container",
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                                        "id": "nonBlocking3",
                                        "columns": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "Column",
                                                "width": "stretch",
                                                "items": [
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                        "id": "toggleKCostDown",
                                                        "weight": "bolder",
                                                        "text": "Cost",
                                                        "wrap": true
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                        "id": "toggleCostUp",
                                                        "weight": "bolder",
                                                        "text": "Cost",
                                                        "wrap": true,
                                                        "isVisible": false
                                                    }
                                                ],
                                                "verticalContentAlignment": "center"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "style": "accent",
                                        "selectAction": {
                                            "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                                            "targetElements": [
                                                "toggleCostDown",
                                                "toggleCostDownChevron",
                                                "toggleCostUp",
                                                "toggleCostUpChevron",
                                                "contentCost"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "bleed": true
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                        "id": "contentCost",
                                        "text": "Some info about costs.",
                                        "wrap": true,
                                        "isVisible": false
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "bleed": true
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Container",
                        "id": "nonBlocking4",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "ColumnSet",
                                "columns": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Column",
                                        "width": "50px",
                                        "items": [
                                          {
                                            "type": "Column",
                                            "width": "70",
                                            "items": [
                                                {
                                                  "type": "TextBlock",
                                                  "weight": "bolder",
                                                  "text": "Open in new tab",
                                                  "wrap": true
                                                }
                                            ]
                                          }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                          ],
                        "style": "accent",
                        "selectAction": {
                            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                            "url": "https://google.com",
                            "title": "Open in new tab"
                        },
                        "spacing": "medium"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "weight": "bolder",
                "text": "Have you found what you are looking for?",
                "wrap": true
            },
            {
                "type": "ColumnSet",
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "type": "Column",
                        "width": "stretch",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "ActionSet",
                                "actions": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                                        "data": "No",
                                        "title": "No",
                                        "style": "destructive"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Column",
                        "width": "stretch",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "ActionSet",
                                "actions": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                                        "data": "Yes",
                                        "title": "Yes",
                                        "style": "positive"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "spacing": "medium",
                "separator": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you still having an issue with this? If so, could you update your post to include the code for your adaptive card? I just tested the Web Chat code you referenced above and it works as expected in that all buttons are disabled, including `Action.OpenUrl` and `Action.ToggleVisibility`, and all input was preserved. Also, which version of Web Chat are you running?

Comment: @StevenKanberg Thanks for your help, this is still an issue for us. I added the adaptive card content in my post. We are running botframework-webchat v4.15.3.

Comment: I just tested your card in the Adaptive Card [Designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) and, while it isn't showing any errors or warnings, neither is it generating a proper card. I would suggest testing your card there to see what isn't correct and fixing it. I suspect that Web Chat is failing to recognize the structure of the card due to the formatting. This is resulting in the unexpected behavior. Be sure to set the target version of Web Chat in the Designer, as well (top right corner of page).